# $.get how to add headers using laravel

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

i want to add this headers

```
headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
},
```

to my `$.get` jquery request

```
$('.wilayas').on('change', function(x) {
        /*             
                    $('.dayras').find('option')
                        .remove()
                        .end() */
        alert(this.value)

        $.get("{{ route('customer.auth.dayras') }}", {
                data: this.value
            },
            function(data, status) {
                alert(data);
                $('.dayras').append(`
             <option value="-">-</option>
        `);
                data.map(dd => {
                    $('.dayras').append(`
             <option value="${dd.id}">${dd.dayra}</option>
        `);
                })
            });
    });
```

am getting the html response instead of json

Comment: Are you not able to use fetch api?

Comment: Try `$.get( "test.php", your_data, your_fn, "json")`

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of the jQuery ajax `headers` option :

```
$.ajax({ 
    headers: {          
        "Accept": "text/json"
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }    
    ...
    ...
});
```

The syntax of the jQuery ajax `headers` option set or overwrite with the `beforeSend` callback function :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "{{ route('customer.auth.dayras') }}",
    data: { foo: bar },
    type: "GET",
    beforeSend: function (jqXHR, settings) { 
        jqXHR.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/json");
        jqXHR.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    }
    ...
    ...
});
```

Comment: i want to use $.get not $.ajax

Comment: @ismailtaibi I think you need to know more about jquery.